# Replacing XML Element

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I have a XML file like this :

```
<Adresses>      
    <Address1>       
        <XPath>//Address/Local[001]/AddressLine1</XPath>       
        <Key>1</Key>     
    </Address1>     
    <Address2>       
        <XPath>//Address/Local[002]/AddressLineA</XPath>       
        <Key>2</Key>     
    </Address2>     
    <Address3>       
        <XPath>//Address/Local[003]/AddressLineBC</XPath>       
        <Key>3</Key>     
    </Address3>     
    <Address4>       
        <XPath>//Address/Local[004]/AddressLineA1</XPath>      
        <Key>4</Key>     
    </Address4>     
    <Address5>      
        <XPath>//Address/Local[005]/AddressLineCD1</XPath>       
        <Key>5</Key>     
    </Address5> 
</Adresses>
```

I am trying to replace Local[002], [Local003], [Local004], and [Local005] with Local[001] in C# using XSLT. I am new to this.
After replacement the XML should look like as follows :

```
<Adresses>      
    <Address1>       
        <XPath>//Address/Local[001]/AddressLine1</XPath>       
        <Key>1</Key>     
    </Address1>     
    <Address2>       
        <XPath>//Address/Local[001]/AddressLineA</XPath>       
        <Key>2</Key>     
    </Address2>     
    <Address3>       
       <XPath>//Address/Local[001]/AddressLineBC</XPath>       
       <Key>3</Key>     
    </Address3>     
    <Address4>       
        <XPath>//Address/Local[001]/AddressLineA1</XPath>      
        <Key>4</Key>     
    </Address4>     
    <Address5>      
        <XPath>//Address/Local[001]/AddressLineCD1</XPath>       
        <Key>5</Key>     
    </Address5> 
</Adresses>
```

tried this:

```
if (xpath.Contains("//Address"))
{
    const string LOCAL = "//Address/XPath";

    if (!dr.IsNull("document"))
    {
        XmlNodeList localNodes = xDoc.SelectNodes(LOCAL);

        if (localNodes != null)
        {
            xpath = xpath.Replace( @"Local[\d{3}]", "Local[001]");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So where are you stuck? C#, XSLT,...?

Comment: Replacing it using C#. I am using .NET Framework 2.0.

Comment: if (xpath.Contains("//Address"))
            {
                const string LOCAL = "//Address/XPath";
                if (!dr.IsNull("document"))
                {
                    XmlNodeList localNodes = xDoc.SelectNodes(LOCAL);

                    if (localNodes != null)
                   {
                        xpath = xpath.Replace( @"Local[\d{3}]", "Local[001]");
                     
                   }

                }

             }

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to replace Local[002], [Local003], [Local004], and
>   [Local005] with Local[001] in C# using XSLT.

**If you want to use XSLT, here is a complete XSLT transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
 "XPath/text()
      [contains(translate(.,'23456789','00000000'),
               '/Local[000]'
               )
      ]">
  <xsl:value-of select=
  "concat(substring-before(., '['),
          '[001]',
          substring-after(., ']')
          )
          "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<Adresses>
    <Address1>
        <XPath>//Address/Local[001]/AddressLine1</XPath>
        <Key>1</Key>
    </Address1>
    <Address2>
        <XPath>//Address/Local[002]/AddressLineA</XPath>
        <Key>2</Key>
    </Address2>
    <Address3>
        <XPath>//Address/Local[003]/AddressLineBC</XPath>
        <Key>3</Key>
    </Address3>
    <Address4>
        <XPath>//Address/Local[004]/AddressLineA1</XPath>
        <Key>4</Key>
    </Address4>
    <Address5>
        <XPath>//Address/Local[005]/AddressLineCD1</XPath>
        <Key>5</Key>
    </Address5>
</Adresses>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<Adresses>
   <Address1>
      <XPath>//Address/Local[001]/AddressLine1</XPath>
      <Key>1</Key>
   </Address1>
   <Address2>
      <XPath>//Address/Local[001]/AddressLineA</XPath>
      <Key>2</Key>
   </Address2>
   <Address3>
      <XPath>//Address/Local[001]/AddressLineBC</XPath>
      <Key>3</Key>
   </Address3>
   <Address4>
      <XPath>//Address/Local[001]/AddressLineA1</XPath>
      <Key>4</Key>
   </Address4>
   <Address5>
      <XPath>//Address/Local[001]/AddressLineCD1</XPath>
      <Key>5</Key>
   </Address5>
</Adresses>
```

**How to initiate an XSLT transformation in .NET is described in the respective MSDN documentation [(`XslCompiledTransform.Transform()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms163431.aspx)**)

**Explanation**:  Overriding the [**identity rule**](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html). Use of the standard XPath functions **[`contains()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-contains)**, **[`translate()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-translate)** and **[`concat()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-concat)** .

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Sample {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(@"data.xml");
        XmlNodeList  nodes = doc.SelectNodes("/Adresses/*/XPath");
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"Local\[\d{3}\]");
        foreach(XmlNode  node in nodes){
            node.InnerText = regex.Replace(node.InnerText, "Local[001]");
        }
        doc.Save(@"data.xml");
    }
}
```